# Add shortcut keys for copy & paste actions to all Swing components

Tags: java, swing

I went through this question [Java - How can i select all rows in JTable using Command+A shortcut in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142602/java-how-can-i-select-all-rows-in-jtable-using-commanda-shortcut-in-mac) on how to add shortcut keys for Mac. I want to know if I can use this to add these shortcut keys to all components or do I have to set for each component like below:

```
For JTABLE:
InputMap im = myTable.getInputMap( JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT );
final int CMD_BTN = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
im.put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_A, CMD_BTN ), "selectAll" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Swing component has a parent InputMap. So you should be able to change that InputMap and the binding should work for all instances of that type. For example to add a binding for all JTable instances you would use:

```
InputMap im = (InputMap)UIManager.get("Table.ancestorInputMap");
```

And for a JTextArea you would use:

```
InputMap im = (InputMap)UIManager.get("TextArea.focusInputMap");
```

To see which InputMap is used by each component check out: [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)

Comment: So I have to set the input map for each binding, there's no other way to set the input map for all components?

Comment: I thought I just answered your question. If I new how to do it for all different types of components in a single statement I would have given that answer. I don't. So I gave you the next best option that I know of. Besides not all components have a "selectAll" Action, so implementing this approach should be relatively simple.

Comment: I have to do this for copy/paste actions too. As of now your approach is the best I guess. Any way I can do this by tweaking the L&F. Just asking